# setScaleType to ScaleType.MATRIX programmatically not work but in xml it work

Tags: android, imageview, scale

this is my code :

```
    LinearLayout imageViewParent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageViewParent);
    ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
    imageViewParent.addView(view);
    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.np);
```

In this code scale type to matrix not work(it fix image to parents),but when I implement this in xml it works fine! 
can every one help me?
thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))
not setBackgroundResource.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
view.setImageResource(R.drawable.np);
```