# images are too far into LinearLayout and HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

how can i set the ranges of Images which are in the HorizontalScrollView

As you can see the images are not so close between themselves, i need them to be close.

This is my code for the HorizontalScrollView xml file:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="5dp"
android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
android:layout_weight="0.2">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

This is what i have tried programmatically.

```
private ImageView getImageView(final Integer image, final int index) {

    imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);

        }
    });

   imageView.setImageResource(image);

    return imageView;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952656/setscaletype-to-scaletype-matrix-programmatically-not-work-but-in-xml-it-work

Comment: Don't use horizontal scroll view for that, instead use `ViewPager`. check this - https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: try defining a fixed width for imageview.

Comment: @mayurvpatel110 i did, but images are so much wide now.

Comment: @OnkarNene i am using a viewpaper already for the center slide. i will try it for the bottom slide.

Comment: @karanvs i will try it too.

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing the xml to

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/itemlistbg"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: what  you mean with android:background="@drawable/itemlistbg", 
what is itemlistbg? how can i get it?

Comment: any custom background you prefer to use